# Не назначил что-то в функции

Tags: c++

Не понимаю почему компилятор выдаёт, что я не назначил что-то в функции. Объясните, как это делать правильно (уже который раз с этим сталкиваюсь).

Ошибки на фото

[image: Ошибки]

```
#include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int n,type;
  void size_activity(int size=0,int leftside=0,int rightside=0,int number=0)
    {
      cout << "Enter the digit of the desired number.";
        cin >> size;
      if( size <= 0)
       {
         cout << "Incorrect digit.The number should be natural." << endl;
       }
      else
        {
          for(int i = 1; i <= size ; i++)
          {
            number=1;
            number=number*10;
            leftside=number-1;
            rightside=number+1;
          }
        }
    }
  void digit_looking(int digit=0)
    {
      cout << "Enter the number of digit , you looking for in the number." << endl;
        cin >> digit;
    }
  void min(int min=rightside,int div=0)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
          if(leftside < a[i] < rightside)
            {
              int n=a[i];
              for(int p = 0 ; p < digit;p++)
                {
                 div=n*10;
                }
              if((n)mod(div)==0)
               {
                 if((n)<min)
                 {
                   min=a[i];
                 }
               }
              cout << "The minimum number, meeting the conditions is " << min << endl;
            }
          else
            {
              cout << "There is no numbers , meeting the conditions" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
  void max(int max = leftside,int div=0)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        if(leftside < a[i] < rightside)
          {
            int k=a[i];
            for(int p = 0 ; p < digit;p++)
              {
               div=k*10;
              }
            if((k)mod(div)==0)
             {
               if((k)>max)
               {
                 max=a[i];
               }
             }
            cout << "The maximum number, meeting the conditions is " << max << endl;
          }
        else
          {
            cout << "There is no numbers , meeting the conditions" << endl;
          }
      }
  }
  int main ()
  {
    cout << "Enter the size of number's raw." << endl;
      cin >> n;
    cout << "Choose : minimum or maximum." << endl;
      cin >> type;
    int a[n];
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
      void size_activity();
      void digit_looking();
      switch (type)
        {
          case 1:
              min();
            break;
          case 2:
              max();
            break;
        }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Откуда компилятор должен взять значение rightside  и подставить в `void min(int min=rightside,int div=0)`. Почему аргумент называется так же, как функция?

Comment: Что такое `rightside`? У вас нет никакого `rightside`. О чем вам компилятор и говорит.

Comment: @CachGl: "Появятся"? Появятся где? И о каком "после выполнения" может вообще идти речь, если никакого выполнения нет и быть не может. Вы еще только компилируете программу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void min(int min=rightside,int div=0)
```

Значения по умолчанию должны быть известны во время компиляции, ктобы компилятор, увидев, что аргумента нет, подставил вместо него нужное значение. А что такое у вас `rightside`, неизвестно.

```
if(leftside < a[i] < rightside)
```

Нигде не описано, что такое `leftside`, `a` и `rightside` - непонятно, что это за переменные.

```
 for(int p = 0 ; p < digit;p++)
```

Здесь не объявленная переменная `digit`.

```
 if((n)mod(div)==0)
```

В С++ нет оператора `mod`.

```
 int a[n];
```

В С++ нельзя объявлять массив с неизвестным компилятору размером.

Все ошибки пересмотреть трудно, начние с выпрявления этих самых простых.

Comment: Все проблемы решил, кроме одной. "В С++ нельзя объявлять массив с неизвестным компилятору размером." Возможно ли как-то ввести плавающий массив / вектор ?

Comment: @CachGl `std::vector`. Либо с помощью `new[]` / `delete[]`.